# Django Creating Two Objects If Don't Exist

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a django app and I need in one view function to get two objects: `token` and `plan` or create them if they don't exist, here the code I'm currently using:

```
def get_or_create_token_and_plan(user):
  try:
    token = Token.objects.get(user=user)
  except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
    token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
  try:
    plan = Plan.objects.get(user=user)    
  except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
    plan = Plan.objects.create(user=user)
  return token, plan

def profile(request):
  user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
  token, plan = get_or_create_token_and_plan(user)
  context = {'token':token, 'plan':plan} 
  return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

I'm trying to figure out a way of improving `get_or_create_token_and_plan()` function, knowing that `token` and `plan` objects will be, in theory, created initially at the same time. Except for exceptions, if I merge both `try, except` structures into a single one will work, like here:

```
def get_or_create_token_and_plan(user):
  try:
    token = Token.objects.get(user=user)
    plan = Plan.objects.create(user=user)   
  except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
    token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
    plan = Plan.objects.get(user=user)        
  return token, plan
```

The main issue with this is that if `token` already exists and `plan` doesn't, the I will get an IntegrityError when creating it again for the same user, but as said, in theory this won't happend because both `token` and `plan` will be created only in this function, so my question is, should I change `get_or_create_token_and_plan` in this case or should I use the later example I said.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your initial function, but 
 you could use
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django provides a [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) function that may be useful to you.  So I think you could do.

```
def get_or_create_token_and_plan(user):
  token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
  plan, _ = Plan.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
  return token, plan
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for! BTW, `get_or_create` returns a tupple, right?. like it would be `token, boolean = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)` to get **only** the object.

Comment: you're right, sorry.  I'll update the answer.